# Get current job name when build with parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible to get current job name in a Groovy script (Active Choice Parameter) when "Build with parameters" is launched to get parameters and previously to run job?

Thanks

I've tried currentBuild, JOB_NAME environment variable, etc. but nothing works before run a job.

Answer (score 0):

before run job you can not get current job name.
if you want you can trigger a job to the other job you have to make 2 jobs then trigger first job to other job and its possible in post action or in during run first job for example :

if you want run a job during running stages use this code :

```
                stage ('step 1') {

            steps {

                job_b = build (job:"job_name_you_want_run", wait: true)

            }

        }
```

if you want run a job at end of a job use post action :

```
post{
 always {
         
   script {

     def job = build job: 'job_name_you_want_run', parameters: [
  $class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'parameter_name', value:parameter_name]]
 }
   }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue using `this.binding.jenkinsProject.name`